# Fill PHP Array by comparing it with MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Guys this is mysql tables output. It show for `month(Value)` get `count(Total)` for a particular disease. Now I have a php `array()` of 12 months and I want to compare with that array and find that if for particular month their is no data returned from table add `0` for that month in other new `array()` of 12 months or else the value found from table.

```
Value | dname      | Total            
5     | Root Canal | 1         
8     | Root Canal | 1
```

my code in php

```
foreach($ResultArray2[1] as $key => $val){       
if(empty($row_d['Value'])){
$ResultArray2[$i][$key] = '0';
else
$ResultArray2[$i][$row_d['Value']] = $row_d['Total'];
```

This is what i get

> ```
>      Array (
> [1] => Array
>     (
>         [1] => 0
>         [2] => 0
>         [3] => 0
>         [4] => 0
>         [5] => 0
>         [6] => 0
>         [7] => 0
>         [8] => 0
>         [9] => 0
>         [10] => 0
>         [11] => 0
>         [12] => 0
>     )
>
> [2] => Array
>     (
>         [5] => 1
>         [8] => 1
>     )
> ```
>
> )

this is what i need 
 Array (

> ```
> [1] => Array
>     (
>         [1] => 0
>         [2] => 0
>         [3] => 0
>         [4] => 0
>         [5] => 0
>         [6] => 0
>         [7] => 0
>         [8] => 0
>         [9] => 0
>         [10] => 0
>         [11] => 0
>         [12] => 0
>     )
>
> [2] => Array
>     (
>
>       [1] => 0
>         [2] => 0
>         [3] => 0
>         [4] => 0
>         [5] => 1
>         [6] => 0
>         [7] => 0
>         [8] => 1
>         [9] => 0
>         [10] => 0
>         [11] => 0
>         [12] => 0
>     )
> ```
>
> )

Comment: where is month or date column in your table for comparing?

Comment: What does that `$i` do? You wanna generate an array which will have 12 indexes each mapped to the count of disease in that month right?

Comment: here $i is no. of disease..i have 5 types of disease..so it will generate 5 different arrays each having its own month & count in that array.

Comment: What format is your row data in? I assumed you'd just be querying a table...

Comment: Never mind, ignore me; I misread it as $ResultArray2 being the result of the query, but it's actually your output.

Comment: guys i didn't got any of yours working for me.. :(

Comment: @KaushilRambhia All of the answers here should work; if they're not then the problem is probably elsewhere in your code. If you post the while bit of code that gets the data rather than just that loop we might be able to help.

Comment: dude i did a modification in my code it wroked

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correct then

```
$finalResult = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($querResult)) {
   if(!is_array($finalResult[$row->dname]) {
      $finalResult[$row->dname] = array_pad(array(), 13, 0);
   } 
   $finalResult[$row->dname][$row->Value] = $row->Total;
}
```

Basically the code checks if there is already an array exists for a particular disease. If not it creates an array of size 13 [to ignore 0] padded with value 0 and updates the value on the go. Here disease becomes a key of outer array. You can use an map to disease name to integer ID if you wish to. In that case

```
$finalResult[$map[$row->dname]][$row->value] = $row->Total;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$counts = array_fill(1,12,0);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
  $counts[$row['Value']] = $row['Total'];
}
```

*Edit:* Since you seem to want to get all the diseases, it may be easier to do the whole thing as one query, like so:

```
SELECT name,
SUM(IF(Value=1,1,0) as month1,
SUM(IF(Value=2,1,0) as month2,
SUM(IF(Value=3,1,0) as month3,
...
FROM tablename
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: dude i m having already having array like `$ResultArray2[1] = array_fill(1,12,'0');`

Comment: @KaushilRambhia (having now seen your code edit) so why aren't you doing that for $ResultArray2[$i] as well? Seems like the simplest way. Although given what you want overall I'd go for the SQL approach I edited into my answer.